# Create custom components in Watch OS3

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-3

I have recently gone through the video of WWDC 2016 - 806 (Design guidelines). In watchOS 3 there is now SpriteKit and SceneKit available.

Anyone tried making a custom component as iOS in watchOS. We can't subclass a interface. **So, how is it possible to make custom components.**

Custom components I mean to create custom sliders, buttons, etc.

**As SpriteKit and SceneKit are available how can we create animation and custom views.** Without using any image animations.

I have tried to search several places but can't find much resources and the animations mostly are done through images. So if anyone can help me would be appreciated.